# Robocopy/Powershell - Delete all folders (and their contents) from root directory... but leave System Volume Information

Tags: powershell, robocopy

Should be easy but I just can't get it. I use Robocopy with Powershell and a USB stick.  I want to delete everything off the stick and then begin my copy.  The copy part is easy - but the problem I have is the delete part.
I tried
`rmdir D:\*`
but ran into execution policy issues.

I then tried
`rmdir D:\* -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`
but that removes the System Volume Information as well.

Any help would be appreciated.
P.S. I've had a stroke and am re-learning all over again.  It's a simple solution I know... but I just can't remember.

Comment: What kind of execution policy issues?  i.e., what was the error?  Also, what is the problem with removing the System Volume Information from the usb drive?  In most cases this can be safely deleted from removable 'non-system' drives.

Comment: "You do not have sufficient rights to remove this directory". I get this for all directories in the root folder of my USB stick.  Unsure why, they're just MP3's.  Removing the System Volume Information is safe... part of me just wants to know the proper way to delete all directories (syntax) of non-system files.  Thanks again.